# Include _spec.rb files in simplecov coverage reports

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, simplecov

I'd like to be able to check the coverage of code within an RSpec spec file itself. (It's a bit unusual, but I suspect there's some unused code within the file) Currently, if I change the configuration of RSpec in rails_helper.rb from

```
require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start 'rails' do
  minimum_coverage 90 # Not the real number
  maximum_coverage_drop 5
end
```

to

```
require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start do
  minimum_coverage 90 # Not the real number
  maximum_coverage_drop 5
end
```

I can see coverage for some files within the spec folder, such as spec/factories/users.rb , but not the spec file itself, such as spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to build a custom `SimpleCov` profile. But make sure first, that you're including `simplecov` at the top of your `rails_helper.rb` file, prior any code. If that's ok, you may use the following:

```
SimpleCov.start :my_profile do
  # add some rules here
end
```

[By default](https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov/blob/a61649f45aea5ced4f0be7c748895daa8cf97657/lib/simplecov/defaults.rb#L37-L42), only `:bundle` (exclude paths containing `/vendor/bundle/`)  and `:root` (exclude all files outside of simplecov root) filters are included, i.e. your spec file should get covered.

Make sure you're not using `spring` when you run your coverage report, since it also messes up the things, run `spring stop` before running your tests. If you still want to use `spring` with `simplecov`, there's a [section in docs](https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov#want-to-use-spring-with-simplecov) describing that.

Last, you can use https://github.com/danmayer/coverband to find your dead code. I haven't used it myself, but `simplecov` author [recommends](https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov#want-to-find-dead-code-in-production) it.